# How to calculate $\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ in R

Tags: statistics, regression

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate $\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2$ in R, specifically identifying it in either the aov function or $\operatorname{lm}(y\sim x)$ function.
I am trying to use it to calculate the s $\{\hat{Y}\}$ value in a regression confidence interval.

Comment: and R is what, a certain computer language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the command $\operatorname{anova}(\operatorname{lm}(x\sim1))$ then the sum of squares due to error should be exactly $\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2$.

Alternatively sum((x-mean(x))^2) should do it.

I tried it with an example:

> anova(lm(x~1))
> Analysis of Variance Table
>
> Response: x
> Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
> Residuals 24 34.516  1.4382
>
> sum((x-mean(x))^2)
> [1] 34.51644

The first command gives you $34.516$ and the second gives you $34.51644$.